# Keeping record of save place in Delphi

Tags: delphi

Well, I'm making a program in Delphi that uses a TValueListEditor object to store Keys and Values and save them to a .txt file. I used this functions to do so:

```
procedure TfrmInserir.FormClose(Sender: TObject; var Action: TCloseAction);
   begin
      vlePalavras.Strings.SaveToFile('C:\Users\Felipe Knop\Desktop\Felipe\Algoritmos\Delphi\Projetos\Palavras Japonês\Lista.txt');
   end;

procedure TfrmInserir.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
   begin
      vlePalavras.Strings.LoadFromFile('C:\Users\Felipe Knop\Desktop\Felipe\Algoritmos\Delphi\Projetos\Palavras Japonês\Lista.txt');
   end;
```

In my computer it works fine because the saving path is in the code, but I wanted to share the program with my friends and wanted them to be able to choose the path. Thought about using a TSaveDialog, but since I never used, I don't know if it would do what I want. I need a way to make the user able to choose a path just once and the file will be saved there every time he closes the form. Any ideas?

EDIT: Thank you both Jason and Sean for you answers. Both helped me alot and I figured out a way to make the program more interactive and give my friends the possibility to even share their lists. May sound dumb but it's one of my first programs and I really thank you alot.

Comment: Use a TSaveDialog, and persist the last saved filename in your favoured mode of small-data persistence, eg: Ini file, registry, xml file etc.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for HKCU in the registry

Answer (score 2):

Firstly I would suggest not using the FormCreate to load things from file. If its excepts or fails for any reason your form won't load. Create a method called something like "FormInit" and call this after your have created the form, then show it. Allows for better handling of FormInit issues. Same for closing down the form, have a FormDeInit and call it in the "CloseQuery".

Onto your question. I use "ForceDirectories" to ensure that the path chosen exists for saving. This will return false if the directory couldn't be created, true in all other cases. Again you can handle the error nicely when you can't create the folder.

The save dialog is fine for saying where to store the file, however when you run up again how do you know where they set this the last time? Answer you don't, you need to store that somewhere. So the answer here is to simply store your initial configuration in a known place or ask them where it is. I prefer to have base configurations stored in a known place, and store the location of other configs in there. For simplicity lets stay at one level.

If you need to have a known location then use the following calls

```
 ExtractFileDir(Application.ExeName);
```

This will give you the directory in which the application executable is running. From here you can attach any directory structure you see fit.

If you choose to use the save dialog to get the directory or the application path, make sure to still use the forceDirectory call to make sure the path exists.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try it now. Meanwhile, is there any way to save the keys and values without the use of any other files? Maybe my question sounds dumb, but just checking =P

Comment: Have a look at TIniFile for storage to disk for name, value pairs. While in memory I would suggest Generics.Collections.TDictionary or a good old string list using name, value. I.E. myStringList.Add("name=value"); string myValue = myStringList.Value["name"];

Comment: About TIniFile, I'll take a look. About the StringList, that's exactly what TValueListEditor does, except it manages better Unique Keys and other stuff. Since I started leaning Delphi not so long ago and don't know much yet, please tell me if I say something wrong.

Just tried ExtractFileDir and it works great, thanks for the tip.

Comment: Sounds like your on the right track. Just a note TStringList allows has a Duplicates property. This allows you to specify what occurs with duplicates. Note though that because I am "old" developer I tend to use classes that have been around for a while. Try it all out and see what works for you :)

Comment: Saving user settings in exe dir is good for portable apps. Otherwise a bad idea. To say without a file, use the registry.